# How to make this for loop run faster?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a data structure and I would like to change the information associated to some of its inputs listed in set1 to 4 using my function. I've written a for loop, but its execution time is very long. Is there any way to speed it up or any other way besides for loop (I can run them separately but it will be a very long script). Thanks in advance...

```
    Set1= {'Andrew';'Mike';'Jane';'Bill';'Adam'};
    Set2={'Romania';'Ecuador';'Singapore';'Norway';'India';'UK'};
    Set3 = {'Liverpool';'Delhi';'New York'};
    Set4 = {'2003';'1992';'1991';'2018';'2011';'2024';'2020'};
    
for A=1:length(Set1);
    for B=1:length(Set2);
        for C=1:length(Set3);
            for D=1:length(Set4);
    SET1 = Set1{A};
    SET2 = Set2{B};
    SET3 = Set3{C};
    SET4 = Set4{D};
    Data = myfunction(structure, SET1, 65,'Categ1');
    Data = myfunction(structure, SET2, 100,'Categ2');
    Data = myfunction(structure, SET3, 90,'Categ2');
    Data = myfunction(structure, SET4, 76,'Categ1');
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What is `set1` that you use as a an argument for `myfunction`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out; Corrected-

Comment: Why are you calling `myfunction` 4 times, but you overwriting its result in the variable `Data`?

Comment: Because of the other arguments like I have 'Categ2' and 'Categ1' and different numbers assigned to them.

Comment: The result of `myfunction` is lost the first 3 times you call it. You store it in `Data` then overwrite it. Can you share what `myfunction` does? If the 4 function calls are independent, you don't need the 4 nested loops. You can just process each list in a separate loop.

Comment: It changes the value of Categ1 and 2 according to the input set to a number. Why the results get lost after three times?

Comment: The first time you call `myfunction`, it will return some value. You're storing this value in `Data`. The second time you call it, it returns another value. You're storing this value again in `Data`, and erasing the previous value. This goes for the 3rd and 4th call of `myfunction`.

Comment: What does `myfunction` do? You say it modifies `Categ1` and `Categ2`? Are these global variables? Do their values also influence the working of `myfunction`? Without a [mre], it is impossible for us to understand your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is slow because you're unnecessarily using 4 nested loops.

You can simply handle each set in a separate loop, as:

```
for A=1:length(Set1);
    SET1 = Set1{A};
    Data = myfunction(structure, SET1, 65,'Categ1');
end

for B=1:length(Set2);
    SET2 = Set2{B};
    Data = myfunction(structure, SET2, 100,'Categ2');
end

for C=1:length(Set3);
    SET3 = Set3{C};
    Data = myfunction(structure, SET3, 90,'Categ2');
end

for D=1:length(Set4);
    SET4 = Set4{D};
    Data = myfunction(structure, SET4, 76,'Categ1');
end
```

You can also drop the temporary variable and write loops as:

```
for A=1:length(Set1);
    Data = myfunction(structure, Set1{A}, 65,'Categ1');
end
 // same for the 3 other loops
```